# calculating and showing a date as 'secs ago', 'mins ago', 'hours ago' etc

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've got a small custom made blog type thing and want to display the date posted next to comments.

I'd like to do it in the format of:

posted 23 secs ago
posted 43mins ago
posted 1hr ago
posted 1day ago
posted  2 weeks ago
...
probably won't get much longer than that because articles older than a month aren't shown.

I can stored the actual date in datetime or timestamp format in MySQL...

Anyone know of a function that's existing for PHP which I could use to do this? I haven't really found anything that suits yet.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/501415#501415

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following function and call it as `format_interval(time() - $saved_timestamp)`, where `$saved_timestamp` is the timestamp of the "event" you are interested in.

```php
function format_interval($interval, $granularity = 2) {
  $units = array('1 year|@count years' => 31536000, '1 week|@count weeks' => 604800, '1 day|@count days' => 86400, '1 hour|@count hours' => 3600, '1 min|@count min' => 60, '1 sec|@count sec' => 1);
  $output = '';
  foreach ($units as $key => $value) {
    $key = explode('|', $key);
    if ($interval >= $value) {
      $floor = floor($interval / $value);
      $output .= ($output ? ' ' : '') . ($floor == 1 ? $key[0] : str_replace('@count', $floor, $key[1]));
      $interval %= $value;
      $granularity--;
    }

    if ($granularity == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
  
  return $output ? $output : '0 sec';
}
```

$granularity is the number of different units to show. For example, `format_interval(32745600)` would return `"1 year 2 weeks"`.

The code I am showing is a reduced version of [`format_interval()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_interval/7.x) implemented in Drupal 7, released under [GNU General Public License v2 or successive](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/LICENSE.txt?h=7.x) license. (See also [COPYRIGHT.txt](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/COPYRIGHT.txt?h=7.x).)
I took off the part that is very specific of Drupal, including the part that handles the string internationalization, and changed the code to use plain PHP functions.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no function built in to PHP to accomplish this, but there do seem to be functions already written for this purpose.

The one [here](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/01/20/php-relative-date-time-string.html) seems to be able to do what you need it to.  (you might need to tweak it a bit)