# PHP * hours ago

Tags: php, date, rss

I have a time string which looks like this

```
2011-06-11T08:51:51Z
```

I'm not sure what this time format is, but I know it's not pretty to look at. Could someone help me convert it to "* hours ago" format

Comment: FYI, the official designation of this format is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculating and showing a date as 'secs ago', 'mins ago', 'hours ago' etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452010/calculating-and-showing-a-date-as-secs-ago-mins-ago-hours-ago-etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$tstamp = strtotime('2011-06-11T08:51:51Z');
```

will give you the timestamp, calculate the number of hours like that:

```
$hours = floor((time() - $stamp()) / 3600);
```

Comment: @freddy K.  That Z comes from the ISO8601 I believe.  And it means its a UTC time...

Comment: The Z specifies Zulu time (ie UTC). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: it doesn't work. I'm parsing RSS, and I just added a new item. It says i added it 7 hours ago.

Comment: That's the time difference to zulu time. You have to adjust that to your current timezone

Comment: How would I adjust it to Britain

Comment: I've just taken away 7 hours from every time. I think that'll work, so im putting this answer as correct

Answer (score 4):

In PHP 5.3, you can use [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

```
$date = new DateTime('2011-06-11T08:51:51Z');
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $now->diff($date);
echo $diff->format('h');
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is convert it into a number (strtotime()), then compare it to the current time (time()) and finally divide the result by 3600 (the number of seconds in an hour).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

1. Get the timestamp of that string: `$timestamp = strtotime($time_to_convert);`
2. Get the actual timestamp: `$actual_timestamp = time();`
3. Substract: `$dif_timestampm = $actual_timestamp - $timestamp;`
4. Pass it to hours: `$hours = $dif_timestampm / 3600;`